# How do I stop Programs from showing up UNDER the toolbar in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, eyefinity, amd-catalyst

I have Windows 7, 64 bit, and a Eyefinity video card.

I have multiple problems, One large on is that the windows, when maximized show up under the semi-translucent task bar.  I thus cannot maximize my windows b/c useful information is hidden and blurred by the task bar.

I can't find anyone online thus far that is both having this issue AND has found a fix.

Comment: can you give us a screen shot?

Comment: I can't yet b/c i don't have enough street cred apparently.  I have to wait to get a higher rank.

Answer (score 1):

Does that happen for every program (e.g. Windows Explorer?)

What are your taskbar settings?

Using

```
[x] Lock taskbar
[ ] Auto-hide taskbar
```

I've never seen this on multiple systems (most running with Ultramon, too).

Out of the blue, I can imagine two reasons: Autohide in combination with something that prevents the task bar from hiding, or specific programs that maximize to screen instead of to desktop.

Comment: Lock Taskbar is turned "ON"  and Auto Hide is turned "off"

Comment: and does it happen for windows explorer, too?

Comment: It looks like windows explorer is working "Normally"

Comment: All other programs do not work normally.

Comment: enable Auto hide would fix this.

Comment: Well, I have tried that, but then when I go to USE the stuff at the bottom, the task bar pops over them.